# DB Connection pool in Servlet or Listener?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I'm thinking of using DB Connection Pool in J2EE.
Database: MySQL

Servlets: http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/columns/connection_pool.html

Listeners: http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html

now which is a better option & why? Also, any working source code will help me save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't go for a homegrown connection pool as in your 1st link. There are a *lot* of factors you need to take account with and those are surely not covered by the example given in that article. Forget about it, don't homegrow a connection pool, it's a way *too* important core piece of your webapplication.

Go for a container managed connection pool with an existing connection pooling implementation like mentioned in your 2nd link. You have nowadays the choice of under each [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) and [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). DBCP is already inbuilt in Tomcat, but it's singlethreaded and thus not really performant when talking about a busy-visited website. Alternatively (and Tomcat-specific), there's also a [tomcat-jdbc](http://vigilbose.blogspot.com/2009/03/apache-commons-dbcp-and-tomcat-jdbc.html) which removes this DBCP limitation, but as it's fairly new, I'd rather go for C3P0 as it's already been thoroughly developed and maintained for ages and is nowadays been very robust and performant.

Comment: It says the last update on C3P0 is 2007-05-21 ?? Does that mean, there are NO updates in the recent times, and NO issues found ???

Comment: It's so good that they couldn't make it better.